# Print Java Object as String

Tags: java, json

I want to convert from `JSon String` to `Java` `Object` and print it to the console. but it's not working:

here is the code:

```
    try {
    //From JSON String to Java-Object (Json encoding)
    Person personObj = new Person(); 

    JSONObject json2Java = new JSONObject("{\"id\":1,\"fullName\":\"name\",\"age\":22}");
    personObj.setFullName(json2Java.getString("fullName"));
    personObj.setAge(json2Java.getInt("age"));
    personObj.setId(json2Java.getInt("id"));

    System.out.println("Json2Java: " + personObj);
    }
     catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Couldn't parse JSON string: " + e.getMessage())
                .build());
    }
```

this is what I get on the console:

```
Json2Java: com.akapoor.ws.testws.model.Person@86fe26
```

Can you tell me where my mistake is and what I have to change?

Comment: Look into `Object#toString()` method. Then override it in your `Person` class.

Comment: In Eclipse you can generate it with ALT+SHIFT+S ans choose generate method toString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working correctly - however to get what you're looking for you need to override `toString` method in your `Person` object.  Here's a simple implementation:

```
public String toString() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Person:\n");
     sb.append("ID: ").append(this.getId()).append("\n")
        append("Full name: ").append(this.getFullName()).append("\n")
        append("Age: ").append(this.getAge()).append("\n");
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Add this to your `Person` object and execute the code again.

Comment: Can u tell me that my client and service are right :

Comment: @user3428776 You don't have any client/service in your question - if you have issues with them, I suggest you post a separate question

Comment: The `StringBuilder` is redundant. You can use normal concatenation here.

Answer (score 0):

- Override the `toString() method in`Person` class to print the data in your required format.
- The `toString()` method is called whenever an Object is printed to the console. Since your Person class does not have a `toString()` method, it calls the `toString()` method of the parent class, which in this case is `Object` and that prints the output that you see.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you´re tring to ensure that your json is being correct parsed, so, your best try is to simple replace the personObj by the jsonToJava, because, once you get your json parsed the way you´re filling your pojo its will always be correct.

Sample:

```
System.out.println("Json2Java: " + json2Java);
```